# New @facebook.com email - API Howto?

Tags: facebook, api, sdk, facebook-opengraph

With the new @facebook.com emails being available for all users I'm wondering if there is an Graph API call that can be made to obtain a users facebook email address?

From what I've seen you can simple take the users alias (as we see in the URL) and slap on the @facbook.com to get the email. Until I cam across a friend who had his FB Id instead of the alias listed on his account.

I tested this by sending an email to myself using myid@facebook.com and myalias@facebook.com. The ID failed to send while the alias sent and was received with no issues.

Ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: myid@facebook.com Is that person your friend?

Comment: Hi Tim, have you been using this method? Can you confirm that using the alias works consistently?

Comment: Tom* And yes I've been using this method, it does work. On times you'll get a random one that runs off an id not an alias.

Comment: @Tom Thanks, and sorry for spelling your name wrong. Is there any way to test whether the alias or id is the correct address? I will be storing this for a user's friend's so that they can send them a private message, and I don't want to store the wrong address.

Comment: I didn't do any form of error checking, as far as I could see at the time there wasn't any way to check (at least not via the API). I've just done a search and discovered this: https://www.facebook.com/help/224049364288051

You may be able to just reference the username (now). That can be pulled via the API of course.

Answer (score 0):

Some people can receive mails from both ID@facebook.com and ALIAS@facebook.com, and some people cannot receive ID@facebook.com with an mailer error saying that it's not in their address book.

I wasn't able to see any pattern here, it was random. Not sure this is an error or a spec.

Comment: I ended up just taking the username and whacking @facebook on the end. It seems to work fine, there's just that random scenario where as you mentioned an ID is also a valid email @ facebook.com